# how to show maven reactor build order only?

Tags: java, maven

As we all have known, use `mvn clean package -DskipTests` command, we will get a `Reactor Build Order` of the maven project. It's very important to use `-pl` in a large software baseed on multi-module. It costs 10 min to publish our project in jenkins, ^_^. It costs 4 min With -pl now. I only want to show the reactor build order, just like `mvn -v`. Using `mvn clean` is ok, but it will do something to current project. Can anyone know ?

Comment: What takes 10 minutes ? Running the build only ? What about tests ? Do you use `-T 4`.. ?

Comment: @khmarbaise Yes, we use `-DskipTests`, the project that contains jpa/thrift/scheduing/jsp/dubbo  is too big.

Answer (score 5):

No, but you can execute only the first step in the life-cycle: `mvn validate`

Comment: i think you're right. With this command, i can make a test of maven refactor build order with `-rf`, `-pl`, `-am`, etc. Thx.

Comment: i think there is an arguemnt named `-so` (--show order) before i utilize `mvn -h`.

Comment: Not sure where you found such argument. See http://maven.apache.org/ref/3-LATEST/maven-embedder/cli.html

Comment: There is no such an argument. i think it maybe exist. But it does not exist.

Comment: @L.Sorry With existing solutions available, this is only way possible.